# CQ custom content finder tab is not working properly

Tags: extjs, aem

I followed the below steps to add a new tab in content finder to retrieve only article pages which are using "geometrixx-media/templates/media-article-page." template under /content/geometrixx-media

- Created a new node under /apps of type sling:Folder
  (/apps/wcm/extensions/contentfinder).
- Added the below 2 properties to the new node(contentfinder)
  extensionGroup="tabs"contentfinder &
  extensionType="contentfinder_extension"
- Copied one of the files (pages.js) in
  /libs/wcm/extensions/contentfinder to the folder
  /apps/wcm/extensions/contentfinder
- Renamed the aritles.js and changed "id" attribute and made the below
  changes to retrieve only article pages of template type
  "geometrixx-media/templates/media-article-page."

**Script file location which I placed:** /apps/wcm/extensions/contentfinder

**file name:** articles.js

**Code:**

```
 {
"tabTip": CQ.I18n.getMessage("Articles"),
"id": "cfTab-Articles",
"iconCls": "cq-cft-tab-icon pages",
"xtype": "contentfindertab",
"ranking": 11,
"allowedPaths": [
    "/content/*",
    "/etc/scaffolding/*",
    "/etc/workflow/packages/*"
],
"items": [
    CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.getQueryBoxConfig({
        "id": "cfTab-Articles-QueryBox",
        "items": [
            CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.getSuggestFieldConfig({"url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/suggestions.json/content"})
        ]
    }),
    CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.getResultsBoxConfig({
        "itemsDDGroups": [CQ.wcm.EditBase.DD_GROUP_PAGE],
        "items": {
            "tpl":
                '<tpl for=".">' +
                        '<div class="cq-cft-search-item" title="{pathEncoded}" ondblclick="CQ.wcm.ContentFinder.loadContentWindow(\'{[CQ.HTTP.encodePath(values.path)]}.html\');">' +
                                '<div class="cq-cft-search-thumb-top" style="background-image:url(\'{[CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.THUMBS_URL(values, 48, 48)]}\');"></div>' +
                                     '<div class="cq-cft-search-text-wrapper">' +
                                        '<div class="cq-cft-search-title">{[CQ.shared.XSS.getXSSTablePropertyValue(values, \"title\")]}</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '<div class="cq-cft-search-separator"></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                '</tpl>',
            "itemSelector": CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.DETAILS_ITEMSELECTOR
        },
        "tbar": [
            CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.REFRESH_BUTTON
        ]
    },{
        "url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/page/view.json/content/geometrixx-media"
    }, {
        "baseParams": {
            "type": "cq:Page",
            "query": "\"cq:template\":\"geometrixx-media/templates/media-article-page\""
        }
    })
]

}
```

**Now new tab(Articles) tab is getting added but First time only it is
   showing all article pages but if we click on any other tab and click
   on articles tab it is displaying all pages(article pages and other
   pages also).**

First time when I clicked on Articles tab showing the below results:
[image]

If I clicked on any other tab(Documents) and clicked on Articles tab showing the below results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have created custom content-finder tab as per use-case to display youtube videos in DAM. This blog can help you out. https://chanchal.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/how-to-add-your-own-content-finder-tab-in-cq5/

Firstly, Issue that seems is change the ranking `"ranking": 10,` may be its conflicting with other that should work,Also for good clarity Add your custom icon `"iconCls": "cq-cft-tab-icon *iconname(for me its youtube)*",` For this you might need to set up structure as follows :
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have verified ranking is unique only, it is not conflicting with other.

Comment: With your js, only issue that i got in my machine was ranking 11 , after changing it to 10, its display the records as per query.

Comment: changed the ranking to 10 but no luck. attached screenshots

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: the query you are firing seems wrong. You can also check the result via browser console. Its retrieving all pages